# maskformatter java number and space

Tags: java, jtextfield, maskformatter

I used maskformatter for my jtextfield.

It works like a charm but the problem is that I cant delete the number in the jtextfield.

```
f = new MaskFormatter( "#" );
f.setValidCharacters("123456789");
```

How can I include the space character so that I can accept space and digits from 1-9?

Answer (score 0):

```
f = new MaskFormatter( "*" );
f.setValidCharacters("123456789 ");
```

accept all characters and include space..

This works for me